# Sql window functions get accumulating column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|id(autoincr)|session_id      |attmpt_counter|
+------------+----------------+--------------+
|0           |ses0            |0             |
|1           |ses0            |1             |
|2           |ses1            |0             |
|3           |ses1            |1             |
|4           |ses1            |1             |
|5           |ses1            |2             |
|6           |ses1            |3             |
|7           |ses2            |0             |
|8           |ses2            |0             |
|9           |ses2            |0             |
+------------+----------------+--------------+
```

For window (partition by session_id order by attempt_counter) I want to get entrance by following math: increment if next value of row 'attempt_counter' is not greater then previous value.
I want to get a table accumulating this rule like this without functions (row cross-rdbms sql as possible)

```
+--------------------------------------------+---------------+
|id(autoincr)|session_id      |attmpt_counter|entrance       |
+------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+
|0           |ses0            |0             |0              |
|1           |ses0            |1             |0              |
|2           |ses1            |0             |0              |
|3           |ses1            |1             |0              |
|4           |ses1            |1             |1              |
|5           |ses1            |2             |1              |
|6           |ses1            |3             |1              |
|7           |ses2            |0             |0              |
|8           |ses2            |0             |1              |
|9           |ses2            |0             |2              |
+------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What do mean by `without functions (row cross-rdbms sql as possible)`, could you explain ?

Comment: @krokodilko I think OP means ANSI, or that it will port to other flavours of SQL

Comment: So do you want do this without window functions ?

Answer (score 1):

This is easy using analytic (windows) functions:

```
SELECT id, session_id,ATTMPT_COUNTER,
       sum( ATTMPT_COUNTER2 ) over (partition by session_id order by id ) as accumulating 
FROM (
select id, session_id,ATTMPT_COUNTER,
       case ATTMPT_COUNTER 
            when lag( ATTMPT_COUNTER ) over (partition by session_id order by id )
            then 1 else 0
        end As ATTMPT_COUNTER2
from table1 t
)
order by id
;
```

If you don't like windows functions, then try this:

```
WITH subquery AS (
    SELECT id, session_id,ATTMPT_COUNTER,
           case ATTMPT_COUNTER
           when ( SELECT ATTMPT_COUNTER FROM table1 t1
                  WHERE t1.session_id  = t.session_id
                    AND t1.id < t.id
                  ORDER BY id DESC
                  FETCH first row only
                  )
            then 1 else 0 end as ATTMPT_COUNTER2
    FROM table1 t
)
SELECT s1.id, s1.session_id, sum( s2.ATTMPT_COUNTER2 ) as accumulating 
FROM subquery s1
JOIN subquery s2 
ON s1.session_id = s2.session_id AND s1.id >= s2.id
GROUP BY s1.id, s1.session_id
order by id
```

If you also don't like WITH clause (common table expression), you must duplicate a subquery in this way:

```
SELECT s1.id, s1.session_id, sum( s2.ATTMPT_COUNTER2 ) as accumulating 
FROM (
   SELECT id, session_id,ATTMPT_COUNTER,
           case ATTMPT_COUNTER
           when ( SELECT ATTMPT_COUNTER FROM table1 t1
                  WHERE t1.session_id  = t.session_id
                    AND t1.id < t.id
                  ORDER BY id DESC
                  FETCH first row only
                  )
            then 1 else 0 end as ATTMPT_COUNTER2
    FROM table1 t
)s1
JOIN (
   SELECT id, session_id,ATTMPT_COUNTER,
           case ATTMPT_COUNTER
           when ( SELECT ATTMPT_COUNTER FROM table1 t1
                  WHERE t1.session_id  = t.session_id
                    AND t1.id < t.id
                  ORDER BY id DESC
                  FETCH first row only
                  )
            then 1 else 0 end as ATTMPT_COUNTER2
    FROM table1 t
) s2 
ON s1.session_id = s2.session_id AND s1.id >= s2.id
GROUP BY s1.id, s1.session_id
order by id
```

---

`FETCH first row only` clause (ANSII SQL variant) works on Oracle 12c and DB2, other databases use `LIMIT 1` clause instead (not compliant with ANSII SQL).

Comment: Great! I did not expect it to be possible in row sql.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `LAG` and `SUM` analytic functions to: first check whether the previous row's attempt counter is greater than the current row's counter; then total the number of accesses from the current and all previous rows for each session.

```
SELECT id,
       session_id,
       attmpt_counter,
       SUM( has_accessed ) OVER ( PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY id ) AS entrance
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         CASE
         WHEN LAG( attmpt_counter ) OVER ( PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY id )
                >= attmpt_counter
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0 
         END  AS has_accessed
  FROM   table_name t
);
```